# Angular Reactive Forms all errors

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

Is it possible to get all the errors on the formGroup and rather than just the individual controls? In angularjs the errors were aggregated on the form. See sample with in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cr77itLEkXkhmopdExpP?p=preview)

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

function MustStartWithValidator (str: string) {
  return (control: SimpleControl) => {
    if (!control.value.startsWith(str)) {
      return {'mustStartWith': true};
    }

    return false;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button type="button" (click)="toggleValidation()">{{btnText()}}</button>
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="myInput" type="text">
    </form>
    <div>Form isValid: {{form.valid}}</div>
    <div>Form hasError mustStartWith: {{form.hasError('mustStartWith')}}</div>
    <div>Form errors: {{form.errors | json}}</div>
    <div>Control isValid: {{form.get('myInput').valid}}</div>
    <div>Control hasError mustStartWith: {{form.get('myInput').hasError('mustStartWith')}}</div>
    <div>Control errors: {{form.get('myInput').errors | json}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  shouldValidate = true;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      myInput: ['', MustStartWithValidator('test')]
    })
  }

  btnText () {
    if (this.shouldValidate) {
      return 'Disable validation';
    }

    return 'Enable validation';
  }

  toggleValidation () {
    this.shouldValidate = !this.shouldValidate;

    const control = this.form.get('myInput');

    if (this.shouldValidate) {
      control.setValidators(MustStartWithValidator('test'));
    } else {
      control.clearValidators();
    }

    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

To be clear, is there a way to get a list of all the errors on the form, including errors from child forms and controls, without recursively checking each *thing* in the form? I would expect if a control in the formGroup has an error, it would show up in the form's `errors` property.

Comment: they are not aggregated because the `errors` returns a mapping between the error name and the error data and it conflicts with your intent. This functionality could be simply implemented by manual traversing the form tree

Comment: sorry but I dont think is possible to retrieve all the errors at once, what you can do is have a map function over your controls and and reduced and conform a big object with all the errors but I think you will like have wich field has the error, no ?

Comment: You can use a validator over the form (a validator can return an array of object). You can use too the new characteristic {updateOn:'submit'} to improve the performance